# How to pass Django context variables into JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a function in Django views.py which passes a context variable called "queues" into an HTML page. In the HTML page, I have a button where if I click it, it should pass the context variable "queues" into a JavaScript function func. However, as shown in the image attached, I see some errors with the way I am doing this. What is the correct syntax to do this?
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQUwy.png)

Comment: Not terribly familiar with Django, but you're missing quotes around your onclick parameter, try this: onclick="func('{{queues}}')"

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of a screenshot, as links may break, screenreaders cannot process the image etc.

Answer (score 2):

In your template :

```
<script>
    let queues = {{queues_declared_in_context_view}};
    ...
    use your javascript variable queues
</script>
```

In addition, here is an interesting article about [safety when passing data from context to templates](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/)

Comment: The resource you shared is super useful to me...thanks a million